# Turning off search highlighting in Janus MacVim

Tags: search, syntax-highlighting, macvim

I accidentally "searched" (`:/u<Enter>`) in MacVim with Janus and now I can't get the highlighting to go away. I really don't need every `u` highlighted.

I really *like* this feature in general, I just need to turn off the highlighting when I'm done with it.

Comment: can you trick it into going away by searching for something else

Comment: Yes, which then highlights that string instead. It still highlights _something_ though, which is what I'd like to toggle.

Comment: Can't you just search for a string that isn't there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To turn off highlighting after a search use `:noh`. The next time you issue a search, highlighting will come back on again automatically.

I have mapped the RETURN key in normal mode to turn off search highlighting like so:

```
 nnoremap <silent> <CR> :noh<CR>
```

So after I'm done searching, I get back into normal mode, hit RETURN then no more highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Search for a string that isn't there, and nothing will be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

From Janus's documentation:

> `<leader>hs` toggles highlight search

from https://github.com/carlhuda/janus

Comment: `<leader>hs` is mapped to `:set hlsearch! hlsearch?<CR>`, which unlike `:noh<CR>`, doesn't turn highlighting on next time you issue a search.